# jQuery: After mouseOver on link#1, 2 and 3 - activate show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a easter egg, where you have to activate some links in the correct order, before the secret is revealed.

I can't get this script to work. I guess I've wrote something wrong, but can't see what it is...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#show').hide();
        var StepOfThree = 0;
        alert(StepOfThree);

        $('#linkone').mouseover(function() {
            StepOfThree = 1;
            alert(StepOfThree);
        });

        $('#linktwo').mouseover(function() {
            if (StepOfThree1 === 1) {
                StepOfThree = 2;
                alert(StepOfThree);
            } else {
                StepOfThree = 0;
                alert(StepOfThree);
            }
        });

        $('#linkthree').mouseover(function() {
            if (StepOfThree1 === 2) {
                $('#show').show();
                alert(StepOfThree);

            } else {
                StepOfThree = 0;
                alert(StepOfThree);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <a href="#" id="linkone">Link #1</a>
    <a href="#" id="linktwo">Link #2</a>
    <a href="#" id="linkthree">Link #3</a>

    <div id="show">This is hidden content</div>
```

The mouseOver on the #linkTwo and #linkThree doesn't even give me an Alert.. What have I done wrong?

Comment: So with this updated version it doesn't alert on step 2 or 3?

Comment: Check out my answer and compare yours... Mine works for me.

Comment: Have a look at my revision, Kenneth B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using jQuery for Javascript primitives? This is horribly wrong! This seems like a case of [jQuery-itis](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bH2OKY_dlTEJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript+%22not+enough+jquery%22+site:stackoverflow.com&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) (sorry for the Google cache link) - use the Javascript equality operator, and don't wrap your `StepOfThree` for a simple numeric comparison:

```
if (StepOfThree === 1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

My guess is you're learning Javascript at the same time as jQuery, right?

---

**Update:**

Okay, here's why your second and third handlers don't work as you expect: when you create a callback like the way you are, you're creating a closure. <strike>In effect, this "seals" the value of `StepOfThree` into the `mouseover` handlers so they never see the updated value.</strike>

Try doing it like this instead:

http://jsbin.com/ovocu/6

This way, you're closing on an object (a "reference" or "pointer" if you're familiar with C/C++/Java) rather than the primitive value of the number itself.

[Some good reading on Javascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

---

**Update 2:** for the simplest working example, here's what [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3659/daniel) had to offer (from the comments below): http://jsbin.com/iluse3

No need to pass around an object. Sorry for any confusion this caused!

Comment: @Bears: I don't think that's how closures in javascript work. It will only "seal" the value as you say if it's passed as an argument to a function, since that's the only way to create a new lexical scope in javascript. It still works fine without storing it as an object property: http://jsbin.com/iluse3

Comment: @Daniel: I haven't looked at your code, but you're definitely wrong about having to pass in the value - that's the whole difference between a closure and a "regular" function.

Comment: @Bears will eat you: If that were true then the module pattern would not work. Functions have access to the variables (not values) and parameters of the function they are defined within -- this is verbatim from Douglas Crawford. The reason why the OP's script does not work is because "StepOfThree1" is not defined. Read the "Creating closures in loops: A common mistake" section in your link to see what I mean when I said it would not "seal" the value. You can only seal values by creating a function factory which overwrites the closure environment with its own variables.

Comment: @Daniel: you're absolutely right. Sorry! I hadn't even noticed that the OP was using a variable called `StepOfThree1`. I'm going to poach your JSBin link and clean up my answer. That's what I get for answering at the end of a long day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in operators to check equivalence? The `is` method is meant to test selectors on jQuery objects, not to test equivalence on regular objects or variables.

Instead of:

`if ($(StepOfThree).is(1))`

Use:

`if (StepOfThree === 1) {`

Comment: I've updated it, but link#2 and link#3 still doesn't work... Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your **vars**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#show').hide();
        var StepOfThree = 0;

        $('#linkone').mouseover(function() {
            StepOfThree = 1;
        });

        $('#linktwo').mouseover(function() {
            if (StepOfThree == 1) {
                StepOfThree = 2;
            } else {
                StepOfThree = 0;
            }
        });

        $('#linkthree').mouseover(function() {
            if (StepOfThree == 2 ) {
                $('#show').show();
            } else {
                StepOfThree = 0;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You are including jquery right?

Answer (score 0):

You have redeclared your variable, overwriting its scope.

```
    ...
    var StepOfThree = 0; 

    $('#linkone').mouseover(function() { 
        var StepOfThree = 1; 
    });
    ...
```

There are two variables there, both named 'StepOfThree'.  To fix, take away the 'var' for all but the first declaration.

Comment: I have updated the code... Can you please look again? Because it doesn't work with LInk2 and 3...

Comment: Variable named "StepOfThree1"?  Use the original name.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your StepOfThree variable is not global - it is inside your $(document).ready function.  Declare it outside:
script open tag
var StepOfThree=0;
$(document).ready stuff

Comment: Nope. It's more subtle than that.